# using new google ads api with 2 resources

Tags: google-ads-api

I have always referred to Adwords API.
now that google is about to deprecate it i'm trying to migrate to google ads api.

I am using keywords_performance_report

I have been looking at the mapping google is providing:

LabelIds-   Select label.resource_name from the resource ad_group_label

I'm using keyword_view resource for all the other data.

 how can I combine these 2 resources in one query?